# Android: unable to vertically align a Button and TextView widget

Tags: android, android-widget, nine-patch

Ok, someone, how the heck does one get a `Button` and `TextView` or subclass of, perfectly aligned vertically?  I have the following XML:

```
 <GridLayout
      android:layout_gravity="top"
      android:useDefaultMargins="false"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
      android:columnCount="3"
      android:rowCount="2">
      <Button                    
         android:gravity="fill_vertical"
          android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
          android:paddingLeft="12dp"
          android:text="@string/stopsButtonText"/>
      <EditText
          android:gravity="fill_vertical"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
          android:textSize="16dp"
          android:minWidth="185dp"/>
      <CheckBox
          android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</GridLayout>
```

When rendered in the emulator, the top of the `Button` and `TextView` are not perfectly aligned as seen here:

[image]

Not very noticeable but when the application is run on a real device this misalignment is very apparent.  Is this a 9 patching issue?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `GridLayout` much it seems that giving it the [Top align](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html#TOP) property ought to align it.

However, I'm not sure why you are using `GridLayout` for this. Using a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` with the property `android:layout_alignTop="@id/idOfEditText"` should make it easy by adding that to the `Button`.

Comment: Thanks for response.  A GridLayout allows me to also horizontally align another row with the same kind of widgets.  Otherwise I will have to use two LinearLayouts which will pose a challenge aligning the widgets horizontally.  Setting top align as you've suggested, by android:gravity="top" does not make a difference.